# Difference between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP latency android

Tags: android, touch, latency, touch-event

So I'm writing a music app for android in which touching various objects on screen causes associated sounds to play. My problem is that there is a huge (200-400ms) latency in terms of recognizing a ACTION_DOWN MotionEvent, at least on my new (2013) google Nexus 7. What's strange is that ACTION_UP (and most if not all of the other MotionEvents) respond with hardly any latency.

Now, I should be clear: the other motion events respond with hardly any latency only *after* the initial ACTION_DOWN has been received. It seems like there is an initial latency for a gesture to get going, but that once you have a gesture and the ACTION_DOWN has been called, all the actions after that respond promptly. So just having playback happen on ACTION_UP doesn't really help, since that still requires the ACTION_DOWN first.

Why is this happening, and what if anything can I do to make the ACTION_DOWN get recognized more quickly?

A couple other notes: I did turn on the "Pointer location" overlay in developer options, and the same lag is found there. On the other hand, I notice that when typing with the onscreen keyboard, the ACTION_DOWN response is quite immediate. So, I don't know what to think.

Thanks!

Comment: Between what events is the latency?  From when you touch to when you get the ACTION_DOWN?  I think in general, that latency should be quite small.  In my app, I handle the fling gesture starting with ACTION_DOWN.  There's no perceptible delay though I haven't actually measured it.

Comment: Yeah, exactly -- between when you touch and when you get the ACTION_DOWN. Testing it out a little more, I think that when you move your finger, you immediately get the ACTION_DOWN followed by ACTION_MOVE. So a flinging gesture wouldn't have that problem, since the ACTION_MOVE would get the gesture going. Can you try putting on the Pointer location developer option, and touch the screen, without moving your finger. Is there a delay before the crosshairs appear?

Comment: I just tried it on 3 devices and they all appear to show the crosshairs immediately.  If there's any delay, I couldn't perceive it.  It tried it with and without moving my finger.  However, not moving my finger by a pixel or two is very difficult, so I'm not sure I truly held my finger stationary.

Comment: Hmm... What were those devices? Was one of them a nexus 7? I appreciate you trying it out, by the way.

Comment: 2012 Nexus 7, Kyocera hydro, LG metro

Comment: Hmm... well, the more I look into it the more it seems like it might be connected with the touchscreen issues on the 2013 Nexus 7. Thanks for your help!